# Is there effective ejabberd spam protection module?

Tags: ejabberd, spam

I am struggling with spam messages on recently enabled s2s ejabberd server. I am receiving a spam message every now and then. I was wondering if there is some kind of mechanism that will filter through messages and drop ones which have, say, cyrillic alphabet in them.

I am aware I can either turn off s2s or allow only specific servers to talk to mine server but I would like to avoid that and explore the option of filtering the messages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since Googling for this takes me to spam protection against new accounts, not spam messages.

Comment: We have stuff, I am trying to add a talk during upcoming ejabberd Advanced Erlang Workshop next tuesday on that topic alone.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond how can I follow that workshop?

Comment: There wil likely be slides and video published in a while.